# How to apply a custom color scale to a column in Google Sheets based on the values in another column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two columns: column `I` contains numeric values, and column `H` contains strings. I want to apply a custom color scale to column `H`, but the colors in the color scale should be based on the values in column `I`.

For example, if the value in cell `I2` is `10`, then I want the value in cell `H2` to be colored red. If the value in cell `I2` is `20`, then I want the value in cell `H2` to be colored yellow. And so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This doesn't look like a practical, detailed question about using Google Sheets. Please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, including the relevant settings like the locale / country setting, as it's relevant for the formula syntax. Add a sample sample, show what you have tried, what you found and why it doesn't meet your needs. Check out the [tour], and the tag wiki for further guidance details.

Answer (score 1):

i think the tabble is like this

[image: my table]

you can do it by add conditional formatting in the format menu
select column H and then add the conditional format

[image]

```
#apply to H1:H1000
#custom formula
=I1=10
```

and then add new formula

```
=I1=20
```

and so on
[image: conditional formatting]
so your table look like this
[image: table]

explanation :
=I1=10 means, if column I is equal to 10,
then turn the formatting to red,
because we apply it to column H,
so the cell that turn to red is column H,
even the formula is referring to column I by custom formula

Comment: Thanks - This does work on single colours  - the problem is that the number of possible values in column `I` isn't known in advance (it can be any value between 0 and 1 and there is a colour scale applied to column `I` which I also want it to apply to column `H`)